# locking cell of dynamic sheet based on value range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I want to use the Excel sheet for Dynamic purpose.

Various product numbers that come from scanning barcodes need to be entered in column A. I want to ensure that if the product number entered (scanned) starts with "200", the cell gets locked automatically after the product number is entered. If any other product number is entered, the cell doesn't get locked.

I also want to change the colour of to red for product code series starting other than "200".

For example:

```
Column A
200412311     - Cell " A1" gets locked
200142390     - Cell " A2" gets locked
200412345     - Cell " A3" gets locked
200154672     - Cell " A4" gets locked
200234578     - Cell " A5" gets locked
100452433     - Cell is not locked
100452412     - Cell is not locked
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe following these steps will get you what you want.

1. Select column A. Right-click and select `Format Cells...`. On the Protection tab, uncheck `Locked`. Click OK.
2. With column A still selected, click `Conditional Formatting` on the Home ribbon, and select `New Rule...`. From there choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format.` There you can enter the formula `=LEFT(A1,3)<>"200"` and set the formatting to red text. Click OK.
3. On the Review ribbon, click `Protect Sheet`. Choose whatever settings you wish for the protection.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor. In the VBA Project Explorer pane, double click the module for the sheet you are working on.
   [image]
   This will open a text editor pane. In that pane paste the following code.

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim c As Range
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
   For Each c In Target.Cells
       If Len(CStr(c.Value)) >= 3 Then
           If Left(c.Value, 3) = "200" Then
               Me.Unprotect
               c.Locked = True
               Me.Protect
           End If
       End If
   Next c
   End If
   End Sub
   ```

   This will lock the cells that start with "200" and leave the others unlocked.